# WPF Can't find XAML Resource in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Page1.xaml which contains a CollectionViewSource as resource like this:

```
 <Page.Resources>

        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyItems" Source="{Binding Path=Products}" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter" >
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="AssetCategory" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>


</Page.Resources>
```

I would like to refresh the CollectionViewSource like this:

```
((CollectionViewSource)FindResource("MyItems")).View.Refresh();
```

But FindResource (or TryFindResource) returns null, I have set this.DataContext = this and all bindings work.
Somebody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That's odd, because according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it should throw an exception if the resource is not found. Which `FindResource` are you using?

Comment: Also, as I understand it, `FindResource` walks up the resource tree. From which item are you calling `FindResource` in relation to where the resource is located? Are they even in the same resource tree?

Comment: There are 2 problems: Be sure the code is run in the context of the `Page` class in which the `this` keyword refers to the current page instance. Secondly be sure that the code is run when the page has been  loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've called the FindResource on a ComboBox SelectionChanged event, with it's selected index set to 0. I think the combox is load before the resource. I've solved it just by checking if the page is loaded:

```
 if (IsLoaded) 
 {
     ((CollectionViewSource)FindResource("MyItems")).View.Refresh();
 }
```